# How to share media file in email with chencha share library

Tags: php, laravel, email, socialshare

I have installed chencha share library [chencha](https://github.com/cybercog/laravel-social-share) and used as below, but getting no media file in mail.

Please help getting stuck into this.

I have code in my controller like below,

```
<?php     
$share = share::load(url()->full(),"Article Title","http://localhost/social-share/uploads/Images/images_0_1545395567.png")->services('email');
return view('front.share',compact('share'))
?>
```

and in my blade file code ,

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Email" class="email" onclick="multimediashare('{{$share}}')">
   <i class="fa fa-envelope-square"></i>Email
</a>

<script>
function multimediashare(url) { 
   window.open(url,"sharer",'toolbar=0,status=0,width=648,height=395');
}
</script>
```

I expect media file in mail body and getting only title of the Image